# put string in variable using <? ?>

Tags: php, html, tags

I think it is sometimes easier to use php tags  instead of echo for example

```
<?
if()
    echo "<img src='' onclick='alert(\"hello\")'/>";
?>
```

instead of that I code like this

```
<?
if(){
?>
<img src='' onclick='alert("hello")'/>
<?}
?>
```

We got rid of backslashing. But what about strings I want something like this:

```
<?
$str="?>
   <img src='' onclick='alert("hello")'/>
<?";
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying?

Comment: Yes, I use the second form. For the third example, store the snippet in an HTML file and load it in using `file_get_contents`.

Comment: I want to put img tag in $str;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [the PHP heredoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
<?php
$str = <<<IMGTAG
 <img src="" onclick="alert('hello')"/>
IMGTAG;

echo $str;
?>
```

Enjoy your code.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [alternative Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) specifically for this kind of formation:

```
<?php if (x): ?>
<div>...</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Also there are short tags:

```
<?= "hello world" ?>
```

This directly prints a string and is equal to:

```
<?php echo "hello world" ?>
```

For string assignment you can do what Magicianred sugested. You could also do it with output buffering:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<div>test</div>
<?php 
$str = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $str;
?>
```

Though output buffering shouldn't be abused for this. Heredoc syntax is the best solution here.

Comment: I think the OP was asking how to do this with string assignments.